# How to read large number of data from InputStream in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, inputstream

In MATLAB I have an InputStream from which I want to read data.

Unfortunately I cannot call the

```
   read( byte [], int, int )
```

function of `InputStream`, because MATLAB does not pass not arguments by reference.

BTW: calling the "`int read()`" function, which reads only one byte, works but is no option.

The background: I want to read a multi-GB BZIP2 file with decompression on the fly (using Apache Commons Compress package).

It seems to me that it is extremely silly that MATLAB provides no way of calling the "`read`" function of `InputStreams`...

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer by definition, but this is a related issue

[Read the data from TXT file inside Zip File without extracting the contents in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456361/read-the-data-from-txt-file-inside-zip-file-without-extracting-the-contents-in-m)