# Read the data from TXT file inside Zip File without extracting the contents in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, zip, unzip

I have tab delimited ascii data in txt files which are zip compressed (and the zip may or may not contain other files). I would like to read this data into a matrix without uncompressing the zip files.

There were a few similar @matlab / @java posts earlier:

[Read the data of CSV file inside Zip File without extracting the contents in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131163/read-the-data-of-csv-file-inside-zip-file-without-extracting-the-contents-in-mat)

[Extracting specific file from zip in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180208/extracting-specific-file-from-zip-in-matlab)

[Read Content from Files which are inside Zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file)

I  have gotten this far thanks to the above - I can identify the .txt inside the zip, but don't know how to actually **read** its contents. First example:

```
zipFilename = 'example.zip';
zipJavaFile = java.io.File(zipFilename);
zipFile=org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile(zipJavaFile);
entries=zipFile.getEntries;
cnt=1;
while entries.hasMoreElements
    tempObj=entries.nextElement;
    file{cnt,1}=tempObj.getName.toCharArray';
    cnt=cnt+1;
end
ind=regexp(file,'$*.xml$');
ind=find(~cellfun(@isempty,ind));
file=file(ind);
file = cellfun(@(x) fullfile('.',x),file,'UniformOutput',false);
% Now Operate Any thing on File.
zipFile.close
```

HOWEVER, I found no example as to how to "`operate anything on file`". I can extract the path within the zip file, but don't know how to actually **read** the contents of this txt file. (I wish to directly read its contents into memory -- a matrix --, without extraction, if possible.)

The other example is

```
zipFilename = 'example.zip';
zipFile = org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile(zipFilename);
entries = zipFile.getEntries;
while entries.hasMoreElements
    entry = entries.nextElement;
    entryName = char(entry.getName);
    [~,~,ext] = fileparts(entryName);
    if strcmp(ext,'.txt')
        inputStream  = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
        %Read the contents of the file
        inputStream.close;
    end
end
zipFile.close
```

The original example contained code to extract the file, but I merely want to read it directly into memory. Again, I don't know how exactly to work with this `inputStream`.

Could anyone give me a suggestion with a MWE?

Comment: If it's compressed, you must extract it if you want to read it. It's like reading encrypted content - you must decrypt it first, don't you?

Comment: well I suppose you could extract into memory and read it in from memory without having to write to hard disk..not sure if the `unzip` function does this - Matlab basically sucks at handling compressed files.

Comment: @GameOfThrows is correct, I want to avoid writing to disk, and want to uncompress into memory. The second example above would be able to extract the file by writing it on the disk. Instead, I want to write the contents into a matrix in memory, and this is where I am stuck.

Comment: [there are many possibilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late, but maybe someone can use it:
(the code was tested in Matlab R2018a)

```
zipFilename = 'example.zip';
zipFile = org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile(zipFilename);
entries = zipFile.getEntries;
while entries.hasMoreElements
    entry = entries.nextElement;
    entryName = char(entry.getName);
    [~,~,ext] = fileparts(entryName);
    if strcmp(ext,'.txt')
        inputStream  = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
        %Read the contents of the file

        buffer = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(inputStream, buffer);
        data = char(typecast(buffer.toByteArray(), 'uint8')');

        inputStream.close;
    end
end
zipFile.close
```